# Solving trigonometry equation - getting variables out from the sin functions

Tags: trigonometry

I want to solve the following equation here in terms of $w$ ($w = \dots$).

$$\sin(x) + \sin(2^{\frac{n+12}{12}}x) = \sin(x+w) + \sin(2^{\frac{n+12}{12}}(x+w))$$

Comment: you want to find $x$ in terms of $w?$

Comment: Sorry. Other way around. w = ... The bit I'm stuck on is how do you get the variables outside of sin when you have $sin a + sin b$ or an equivalent

Comment: (Is this question musically motivated, by chance?)

Comment: Hey! Yes! I bet the sin waves and exponents with base two that gave it away!

Comment: The real giveaway was the base of $2$ with exponents multiples of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that we're looking for a $w$ that makes the expressions equal for all, rather than for some particular $x$. Using, e.g., Fourier series, one can show that unless $2^{(n + 12) / 12} = 1$, that is, $n = -12$, we must have
\begin{align}
\sin x &= \sin (x + w) \\
\sin 2^{(n + 12) / 12} x &= \sin 2^{(n + 12) / 12} (x + w)
\end{align}

So, $w$ is a solution iff both $w$ and $2^{(n + 12) / 12} w$ are multiples of $2 \pi$. In particular this implies that $2^{(n + 12) / 12}$ is rational, which forces the exponent to be integral, that is, that $n$ be a multiple of $12$.

Comment: Well that didn't work as I expected. What I was trying to do was get the width of the repeating unit when combining the sine waves of two notes, one which is n semitones above the other. Now that I think about it I don't really need the +12 there, but still it doesn't work. I could try finding a place where each sine way intersects each other where the y coordinate = 0.

Comment: OK I tried finding a place where the two sine waves meet and where they have the same gradient as that should give me the some results. Just that there are always infinite solutions to sine waves which is really annoying.

Comment: @Dylanthepiguy The answer means that this is only possible when the two notes are an integer number of octaves apart, as the ratio of the frequencies of any other two notes is not rational, which in fact means that the waveform never repeats. Certain ratios are close to rational numbers with small numerators and denominators; for example, the ratio between a note and the note a perfect fifth lower is $2^{7 / 12} \approx \frac{3}{2}$, to which we owe the satisfying sound of that particular combination.